# C# Selenium Wedriver XPATH И FindElement несколько атрибутов

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, test-automation

Пытаюсь программно лайкнуть определенный коммент на ютубе.

Надо найти элемент с двумя атрибутами, как я делаю вы можете увидеть внизу. Данный код возвращает ошибку:

> "{"no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {\"method\":\"xpath\",\"selector\":\"//button[@data-action-type='like'
>   and
>   @data-action='CAUQAhojejEzb2hqZnF2dWJ4ZWJpdTIyMzRneGdid2t1c2hianFlMDQqCzVBM1RzMXJwVW93MAA4AEoVMTE0Njk1OTczMzIwMTIyMDk4Njk5UAA%3D']\"}\n
>   (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)\n  (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.30.477700
>   (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT
>   6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)"}"

```
    //Не рабочий код            
    IWebElement SearchInput3 = Browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@data-action-type='like' and @data-action='CAUQAhojejEzb2hqZnF2dWJ4ZWJpdTIyMzRneGdid2t1c2hianFlMDQqCzVBM1RzMXJwVW93MAA4AEoVMTE0Njk1OTczMzIwMTIyMDk4Njk5UAA%3D']"));
SearchInput3.Click();
```

Рабочий код:

```
//С одним атрибутом работает, но мне так не подходит ибо находит первое попавшиеся совпадение
            IWebElement SearchInput3 = Browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@data-action-type='like']"));
            SearchInput3.Click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        IWebElement SearchInput3 = Browser.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-action='CAUQAholejEzMXlubHhwbzMzeXB5cmEwNGNqbGxod3JiaXU1Mnc1dm8wayoLdERaNnJBOTh4M2MwADgAShUxMDQ4NTM2MTUxNTI4ODg1OTM4NTVQAA%3D%3D'][@data-action-type='like']"));
        SearchInput3.Click();
```

Так заработало